# RuntimeException - unclear cause

Tags: runtimeexception

I get the following crash logged on my App that has been uploaded to the Play store.  But I simply can not work out why this is happening with the report offered.

I have not been able to replicate this crash - any pointers would be helpful.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:3965)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:219)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1875)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:930)

Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:952)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:928)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity (ContextWrapper.java:383)
  at com.example.wb.filterService.manageDrawOverWindows (filterService.java:7)
  at com.example.wb.filterService.onCreate (filterService.java:75)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:3953)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:219)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1875)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: The problem seems to be at `filterService.java` line 7. If that doesn't lead you to the answer, please post that class.